# Sending file multipart from android to server

Tags: android, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I am trying to send a file to a server with the following code

```
private static HttpEntity getHttpEntity(File[] files, List<BasicNameValuePair> 

otherParams, String fileName) {

        MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entity.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        entity.setBoundary(BOUNDARY);
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE, HTTP.UTF_8);
        entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        if (otherParams != null) {
            for (NameValuePair pair : otherParams) {
            entity.addTextBody(pair.getName(),pair.getValue(),contentType);
            }
        }
        if (files != null) {
            for(int i=0;i<files.length;++i) {
            try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(files[i]);                entity.addBinaryBody("file"+i,inputStream,ContentType.create(HTTP.OCTET_STREAM_TYPE), fileName);
                LogUtils.d("added file:"+files[i].getAbsolutePath());// fileBody);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                LogUtils.d("failed to add file");
            }
            }

        }

        return entity.build();
    }
```

The server shows the following log of the arrived file

```
2015-03-05 10:17:06,214 [4] DEBUG Controllers.ApiControllerBase - {[CallingFunction, UploadEventFile], [CallingFile, c:\Dropbox\src\Controllers\ValuesController.cs], [CallingLine, 1804], [CurrentUser, 123456789], [Message, got headers: [{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["multipart/form-data; boundary=com.lenabru.apps; charset=UTF-8"]}]]}
2015-03-05 10:17:06,214 [4] DEBUG Controllers.ApiControllerBase - {[CallingFunction, UploadEventFile], [CallingFile, c:\Dropbox\src\Controllers\ValuesController.cs], [CallingLine, 1805], [CurrentUser, 1234567890], [Message, got content: --com.lenabru.apps
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"; filename="lenkovi-jibrish"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

?PNG

IHDR   ?   ,   ??C?   sBIT ??O?    IDATx?d??%G?%v????%???L ??*??P ???)#B? ? ?'? ??2?A??= !e??fMuwa) ?   $ ?glws7S????    $b????.G? ?? ?????*hf X P?(4??b @ `$?? I jB?? 1???F??? ?@R
#? R?P 0 ! ?TU ` ???#if?? ? 5R VS ?! (0 ???f U w? RX ??P3 ?A
?? h L? ?fBRM?i"
H03 T @C5Pa$D? ?F??`BT?? ?* ?? J? ?L (  BAZ I1 `?* j4?R5??? & ?)i K?@S?__2V ?"0S?r
??? -??L@S????????? ??? }?A ? ??? 3{yq???? ???X?????L?;?????w?g/?? ???nG?V??I? ?
Truncated for the sake of the question
--com.lenabru.apps--
]}
```

The file seems to be received on the server but the following piece of code gives that there are 0 files attached to the request

```
  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count < 1)
           {

               var error = Errors.NoFilesAttached;

               Log(error.Description);

               return Request.CreateResponse(error);


           }
```

I am using the following libraries to send the request 
libraries are downloaded via gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:0.7.2'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6')
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.+'
```

**The question: Why, if the binary part IS received on the server,
the line HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count always returns 0 ?**

Answer (score 0):

This was the culprit 
entity.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

removing this line fixed the problem